# Странное поведение при реализации паттерна "Абстрактная фабрика"

Tags: c#, ооп, абстрактная-фабрика

**Здравствуйте!**

У меня творится что-то неведомое при реализации в своем коде паттерна "Абстрактная фабрика". Вот полный код связки классов фабрики, обернутого в пространство имен:

```
namespace AbstractFactory
{
   public class BaseUser
    {
        protected string login;
        protected string pass;

        public string GetPass() { return pass; }
        public string GetLogin() { return login; }

        public string Login
        {
            set { login = value; }
            get { return login; }
        }

        public string Pass
        {
            set { pass = value; }
            get { return pass; }
        }

        public BaseUser(string login, string pass) { Login = login; Pass = pass; }
    }

   sealed public class SimpleUser : BaseUser
    {
        public SimpleUser(string login, string pass):base(login,pass) {} 
        public void Opera() { MessageBox.Show("SimpleUser!"+login+" -> "+pass); }
    }

   sealed public class AdminUser : BaseUser
    {
        public AdminUser(string login, string pass):base(login,pass) {} 
        public void Opera() { MessageBox.Show("AdminUser!" + login + " -> " + pass); }
    }

    public class FactoryUser
    {
        public static BaseUser CreateUser(int type, string login, string pass)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case 1: return new SimpleUser(login, pass);
                case 2: return new AdminUser(login, pass);
            }
            return new BaseUser("", "");
        }
    }

}
```

**Вот код реализации:**

```
AbstractFactory.AdminUser admin = AbstractFactory.FactoryUser.CreateUser(2, "User1", "12345");
AbstractFactory.SimpleUser user = AbstractFactory.FactoryUser.CreateUser(1, "User2", "1234567890");

...

user.Opera();
```

На что VisualStudio выдает мне ошибку, которая заявляет, что я забыл преобразовать **AdminUser/SimpleUser** к **BaseUser**...но они же наследники, а значит, так можно!

```
  Cannot implicitly convert type 'AbstractFactory.BaseUser' to 'AbstractFactory.AdminUser'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: Антошка, конечно же ты тупишь... =)

Comment: Ну дык укажи где именно, умник =)

Comment: нимагу, я тоже сижу и туплю...

Comment: ты пытаешься юзера к админу преобразовать

Comment: @Gorets, не, то я просто опечатался...в коде не так...исправил.

Comment: всеравно по коду неправильно, сейчас CreateUser(1 - вернет юзера, а ты его к AdminUser admin приобразуешь

Comment: Неа, все равно никак...тем более, что эта ошибка возникла бы в рантайме, а она возникает еще на уровне компиляции - подсвечивается и комментируется.

Comment: чтоб заработало надо сделать :  
1) public void Opera() {} - добавить метод в класс BaseUser  
2) поменять код использования на:

    AbstractFactory.BaseUser admin = AbstractFactory.FactoryUser.CreateUser(2, "User1", "12345");
    AbstractFactory.BaseUser user = AbstractFactory.FactoryUser.CreateUser(1, "User2", "1234567890");

Comment: @jmu, это будет уже совсем не тот паттерн! Если у двух классов наследников( админского и юзерского ) будет совершенно разный функционал? Не один общий метод, а два разноименных, ни как не связанных друг с другом и с родительским классом?

Comment: в приведеном коде кроме factory method никаких паттернов нет. от предложеные изменения позволяют человеку использовать наследование. никакие новые патерны не прибавятся и не убавятся. 
<p/>
для того чтоб было хоть немного похоже на фабрику надо чтоб UserFactory - абстрактный класс, метод createUser сделать абстрактным. и добавить одну имплементацию (напр DefaultUserFactory).
<p/>
для того чтоб были варианты нужно еще одну имплементацию UserFactory, и напр сделать еще 2 реализации классов SimpleUser, AdminUser которые наследуются от них же или от BaseUser.

Answer (score 6):

Среда разработки не сошла с ума, я вам гатарнтирую=)

С чего вы взяли, что можете преобразовать один класс к другому сестринскому классу?

```
AdminUser admin = new SimpleUser(login, pass); // Fail
```

Вообще-то всегда делалось

```
BaseClass/*Interface*/ Obj = new ChildClass(args);
```

К тому же у вас `.CreateUser.CreateUser (` исправьте, а метод `CreateAdmin` вообще отсутствует.

Если вы делаете наоборот, вы фактически **лишаете** объект функциональности, когда в первом случае вы функциональность **расширяете**.

---

У Вас метод `CreateUser` возвращает `BaseUser`, а Вы пытаетесь присвоить его к Admin(Simple)User, из-за этого возникает ошибка.

> но они же наследники, а значит, так можно!

Нет, не значит:

**Доказательство:**

пример:

```
public void SomeMethod(BaseUser user)
{
    user.Opera(); // Fail метод отсутсвует
}
```

даже если вызывать

```
SomeMethod(new AdminUser());
```

пример 2:

```
public void SomeMethod(AdminUser user)
{
    user.Opera(); 
}
```

если вызвать

```
SomeMethod(new BaseUser()); // Fail метод отсутсвует
```

P.S. и на абстрактуную фабрику это совсем не похоже, обычная, не более.

Comment: Это все очевидные опечатки...Это, например:

      AdminUser admin = new SimpleUser(login, pass); // Fail

Уже давно исправил - тоже опечатка была. Извините за опечатки, понимаю, запутывают на пустом месте...

Comment: насчет последнего согласный, это больше похоже на паттерн "фабричный метод", хотя мне кажется пример был скатан с книжки =)
ЗЫ как можно опечатываться? ты тут код перенабераешь чтоли?

Comment: Не, ничего не скатано. Код полностью писан мною. Но за доказательства спасибо! И правда, получалось, что я дочернему классу присваивал родительский...тупо...тупо.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы имплементировал фабрику так:

```
public abstract class BaseUser
{
    public string Login { get; protected set; }
    public string Pass { get; protected set; }

    public BaseUser(string login, string pass)
    {
        Login = login; Pass = pass;
    }

    public abstract void Opera();
}

sealed public class SimpleUser : BaseUser
{
    public SimpleUser(string login, string pass)
        : base(login, pass)
    {
    }

    public override void Opera()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SimpleUser!" + Login + " -> " + Pass);
    }
}

sealed public class AdminUser : BaseUser
{
    public AdminUser(string login, string pass)
        : base(login, pass)
    { 
    }

    public override void Opera()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AdminUser!" + Login + " -> " + Pass);
    }
}

public class FactoryUser
{
    public static BaseUser CreateUser(int type, string login, string pass)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case 1: return new SimpleUser(login, pass);
            case 2: return new AdminUser(login, pass);
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Имплементация абстрактной фабрики (жидковатой какой-то в твоем случае) будет, наверное, выглядеть так:

```
public interface UserFactory
{
    BaseUser CreateUser(string login, string pass);
}

public class AdminUserFactory : UserFactory
{
    public BaseUser CreateUser(string login, string pass)
    {
        return new AdminUser(login, pass);
    }
}

public class SimpleUserFactory : UserFactory
{
    public BaseUser CreateUser(string login, string pass)
    {
        return new SimpleUser(login, pass);
    }
}
```